# Regex-replace - Insert character N-times based on result's index

Tags: regex, replace, formatting, notepad++, unminify

Currently I'm using Notepad++. I'd like to keep this just to text editing programs, but if this function's not in N++ but in something else, I can download it.

Let's say there's a chain of minified HTML that I'm hoping to make legible again. No spacing, everything's on one line.

```
<div><div><div><div><div>
```

I've already got a simple regex replace expression to split up the tags.

Replace (<.*?>) with \1\n\t

```
<div>
    <div>
    <div>
    <div>
    <div>
```

I'm wondering if, purely through regular expressions, there's a way to add an addtional \t to each line based on the number of results.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
```

I'm aware there are practical issues with the question. I could easily find an HTML formatter, or in 5 minutes write some JS to do it for me, but I'm mainly trying to expand my understanding of the capabilities and limitations of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Notepad++ , install the XMLTools plugin.

Then select `Plugins > XML Tools > Pretty Print (xml only with line breaks)`

and you  get (foo added for clarity)

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>foo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good suggestion, though it doesn't quite answer the core question about modifying the regex based on the number of matches or current result index.